# Swagger UI generated locally but page not found on Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, swagger

I've built a RESTful API with Python and Flask, and deployed it on Heroku. The API works fine but I can't access my swagger UI page, I get a 404 error, but when I run it locally I don't have the problem.

I saw many posts saying that the problem could come from the HTTPS connection, so I specified the different schemes in my `swagger.yml` file but it doesn't change anything.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: my swagger file
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: my title
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

host : myapi.herokuapp.com
basePath: /api
schemes: [http, https]

paths:
  /spread:
    get:
      operationId: spread.read_all
      tags:
        - Spread
      summary: Read the file containing all calculated values
      description: Read the file containing all calculated values
      parameters:
        - name: length
          in: query
          type: integer
          description: Number of people to get from people
          required: false
        - name: offset
          in: query
          type: integer
          description: Offset from beginning of list where to start gathering people
          required: false
      responses:
        200:
          description: description
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              properties:
                exp_spread:
                  type: string
```

And here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
flask
pandas
gunicorn
connexion
```

I'd just like to access my swagger documentation page like I do locally, by typing `https://myapi.herokuapp.com/api/ui`.

Comment: After I saved this question, I made a test and the swagger.json file is generated on heroku platform, so the problem really comes from UI ..

Comment: Which Swagger library or code generator are you using? When you say, "I made a test and the swagger.json file is generated on heroku platform" does this mean the `swagger.json` gets built dynamically and saved on the filesystem?

Comment: Yes, it gets build dynamically based on swagger.yml and it's accessible. I use the package Connexion, does it answer your question ?

Comment: It looks like that's not a real file, so it should be okay. Please [edit] your question and show your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`.

Comment: Here is my requirements.txt


`flask
pandas
gunicorn
connexion
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `requirements.txt` to depend on

```
connexion[swagger-ui]
```

instead of just `connexion`, then redeploy. [The UI isn't installed by default](https://github.com/zalando/connexion#the-swagger-ui-console):

> The Swagger UI for an API is available through pip extras. You can install it with `pip install connexion[swagger-ui]`. It will be served up at `{base_path}/ui/` where `base_path` is the base path of the API.